# How can I know my GAN does converge?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan, generative-models

I am training my GAN, and by looking at the loss curves of the generator and discriminator, I think I am going on the right way because from [**this blog**](https://machinelearningmastery.com/practical-guide-to-gan-failure-modes/), my curves look reasonable:

> A stable GAN will have a discriminator loss around 0.5, typically between 0.5 and maybe as high as 0.7 or 0.8. The generator loss is typically higher and may hover around 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, or even higher.

But how do I know when I should stop training. Unlikely to other types of network when we only have a loss curve, GANs have two. I know using FID or Inception scores may work but I am wondering is there any other heuristic way to determine?

Comment: Are you checking also Mode collapse?

Comment: "[...] but I am wondering is there any other heuristic way to determine?" yes, simply have a look at the outputs of `G` after a certain number of epochs and check how good the results are in your opinion.

Comment: @CarlosMougan no, I just want to determine when shoud I stop training

Comment: @Sammy not a good idea as we can not observe every generated images and it should not be fair